# Error during Creation of VPC in AWS via Ansible

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to create a VPC with the following code.

```
 - name: VPC | Creating an AWS VPC inside mentioned Region
   local_action:
     module: ec2_vpc
     region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
     state: present
     aws_access_key: 
     aws_secret_key:
     cidr_block: "{{ vpc_cidr_block }}"
     resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}-vpc" }
     subnets: "{{ vpc_subnets }}"
     internet_gateway: yes
     route_tables: "{{ public_subnet_rt }}"
   register: vpc
```

passing the `localhost` as the `host`. 
But I am facing the following error.

An exception occurred during task execution. The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Merv/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462873251.31-168428606517499/ec2_vpc", line 2944, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Merv/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462873251.31-168428606517499/ec2_vpc", line 731, in main
    (vpc_dict, new_vpc_id, subnets_changed, igw_id, changed) = create_vpc(module, vpc_conn)
  File "/Users/Merv/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462873251.31-168428606517499/ec2_vpc", line 339, in create_vpc
    previous_vpc = find_vpc(module, vpc_conn, id, cidr_block)
  File "/Users/Merv/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462873251.31-168428606517499/ec2_vpc", line 199, in find_vpc
    previous_vpcs = vpc_conn.get_all_vpcs(None, {'cidr': cidr, 'state': 'available'})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_all_vpcs'

fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_name": "ec2_vpc"}, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/Users/Merv/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462873251.31-168428606517499/ec2_vpc\", line 2944, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/Users/Merv/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462873251.31-168428606517499/ec2_vpc\", line 731, in main\n    (vpc_dict, new_vpc_id, subnets_changed, igw_id, changed) = create_vpc(module, vpc_conn)\n  File \"/Users/Merv/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462873251.31-168428606517499/ec2_vpc\", line 339, in create_vpc\n    previous_vpc = find_vpc(module, vpc_conn, id, cidr_block)\n  File \"/Users/Merv/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462873251.31-168428606517499/ec2_vpc\", line 199, in find_vpc\n    previous_vpcs = vpc_conn.get_all_vpcs(None, {'cidr': cidr, 'state': 'available'})\nAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_all_vpcs'\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

I moved my boto version to 2.40.0 yet facing this issue.

Comment: @arbabnazar ... I used some of your examples on git.

Comment: Which version of Ansible are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, it a bug in boto library. 
Found this: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/1772

For a temporary fix(as mentioned in the link):
To manually fix you can

```
add into each init.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ec2/init.py

your endpoints for example...

I added to the RegionData for this...
'eu-west-1a': 'ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
'eu-west-1b': 'ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
'eu-west-1c': 'ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
```

Answer (score 0):

yes It is a bug in the boto library. I installed the latest one. Also, this error persists if, the region name is wrong. So i changed my "{{ vpc_region }}" and this error went away.